# Fortify SCA Parallel Analysis only uses one CPU

Tags: fortify

I want to scan a large application but the default settings generated by the Fortify Scan Wizard result in scans that take several days to complete. In order to speed this process, I looked for and found some options for "Parallel Analysis Mode", as HP calls it, on page 57 of the HP Fortify SCA User Guide v4.00.

In the section of the batch script which generates the FPR, I added `-j 6` to the line which starts the scan:

```
%SOURCEANALYZER% %MEMORY% %LAUNCHERSWITCHES% -b %BUILDID% -scan -f %FPR% -j 6
```

Unfortunately, that didn't work. Even after the scan kicks off (post-translation), only one CPU is used.

Frustrated, I read this:

> After installing SCA and completing the post‐installation steps, you
>   will need to add a couple properties to your SCA configuration file to
>   enable parallel processing.

These properties are listed as having defaults, but I tried to add them anyway. No dice. Fortify still only uses one CPU.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried %SOURCEANALYZER% %MEMORY% %LAUNCHERSWITCHES% -b %BUILDID% -j 6 -scan -f %FPR% 

The j value may not be getting passed. You can check the Fortify log to see what the actual command looked like. It may also be having problems with memory. If you do not set the worker memory value, it will inherit from the main process. So if you're passing 3G as the Xmx value, with 6 threads you're using 21G of memory. (3G for the controller and then 3G for each thread).

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet, so here's a possible answer.

Try running from the command line without using the generated script from the wizard.  For what it's worth, I have had nothing but bad results when using their script.

Start with a basic scan and add the switches on the CLI.  You didn't say what language you were scanning, but here are the Maven switches I use to multi-thread.

```
-Dmaven.sca.64bit=true
-Dmaven.compiler.fork=true
-Dfortify.sca.tests.exclude=true
-Dfortify.sca.Xmx=12000m
```

Give that a shot, or use your compiler's version and see what happens.